# PHP stripos() return only false

Tags: php, stripos

I'm making a filter of Badword that return true if their is a bad word in a string.
but what happen is that whatever the user write the code return false.

I already tried to convert the arguments of `stripos()` to string (just in case) but still.
I tried `preg_match()` with `"/$word/i", $_POST['message']`

here is my function for the checking:

```php
function MessageBad(){
    $BadWord = false;
    $bannedwords = file("bannedwords");
    foreach($bannedwords as $word) {
            if(stripos($_POST['message'], $word) !== false){
                    $BadWord = true;
            }
    }
    return $BadWord; 
}
```

but `stripos($_POST['message'], $word) !== false` always return false even when I enter only a badword from the bannedwods list...

Comment: You might need some echo/log lines here to see what's going on. Between your foreach and if, try `echo "Does {$_POST['message']} contain $word? ".(stripos($_POST['message'], $word))."\n";`

Comment: what does `print_r($bannedwords)` give you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the strings returned by `file()` include the newline character at the end of each line. So `$word` ends with a newline, and will only match if the bad word is at the end of the line.

Use the `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` flag to remove the newlines.

```
$bannedwords = file("bannedwords", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

You should also break out of the loop once you find a match, there's no need to keep checking other words.